# How to minify a single module

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

I'm trying to minify node.js style modules for [Espruino](http://www.espruino.com) (a microcontroller that runs JavaScript). These modules often have hidden internal constants and convenience functions defined, and I want to collapse those down.

As a very contrived example, let's say I have:

```
var C = {
CONST1 : 32,
CONST2 : 64
};

function Foo() {
}

Foo.prototype.C = {
  ONE : 1,
  TWO : 2
};

function doStuff(x) { 
  return x+1;
}

Foo.prototype.getConst = function (x) {
  return doStuff((x==this.C.ONE) ? C.CONST1 : C.CONST2);
}

exports.foo = function() { return new Foo(); };
```

I'd like to minify this down to:

```
function Foo(){}Foo.prototype.C={ONE:1,TWO:2};Foo.prototype.getConst=function(a){return a==this.C.ONE?33:65};exports.foo=function(){return new Foo};
```

However currently I'm using the closure compiler online service and this will either do a simple minification in 'Simple' mode (not folding in the hidden `C` and `doStuff`):

```
var C={CONST1:32,CONST2:64};function Foo(){}Foo.prototype.C={ONE:1,TWO:2};function doStuff(a){return a+1}Foo.prototype.getConst=function(a){return doStuff(a==this.C.ONE?C.CONST1:C.CONST2)};exports.foo=function(){return new Foo};
```

or on 'Advanced' it'll go mad, rename the functions and remove everything:

```
function a(){}exports.a=function(){return new a};
```

So how do I tell it to keep all children of `exports` and everything referenced by those children intact (with the same names)?

Wrapping the code in:

```
(function(){
  ...
})();
```

Has the desired effect, but then I have to strip out `(function(){` and `})();` from what is returned, which seems like a bit of a cludge.

Or is there another minifier (it doesn't have to be online) that would handle this correctly?

Comment: [uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2)? it's kinda standard tool for the job...

Comment: You can try it at http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/#demo - but I can't find a way of doing what I described above. Are there certain switches at the command-line that do it?

Comment: hold on... what do you mean by "folding"? do you want to obfuscate local variables like `doStuff`?

Comment: Not obfuscate, but 'inline' where appropriate. For instance in my example, `C.CONST1` is replaced by its actual value, and `doStuff` is inlined and the addition is pulled inside the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like the only solution was to do as I'd originally mentioned in the question, regardless of how much of a cludge it was:

Wrap the code in:

```
(function(){
  ...
})();
```

Pass it to the closure compiler with SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS, and then strip out `(function(){` and `})();` from the beginning and end of the response.

This allows the closure compiler to do constant folding, to completely remove the `C` array in a lot of cases, and to really reduce the code size.

So with the example above, instead of:

```
var C={CONST1:32,CONST2:64};function Foo(){}Foo.prototype.C={ONE:1,TWO:2};function doStuff(a){return a+1}Foo.prototype.getConst=function(a){return doStuff(a==this.C.ONE?C.CONST1:C.CONST2)};exports.foo=function(){return new Foo};
```

I get:

```
function a(){}a.prototype.C={ONE:1,TWO:2};a.prototype.getConst=function(a){return(a==this.C.ONE?32:64)+1};exports.foo=function(){return new a}}
```

Which is a pretty significant saving in not only code size, but also the memory needed to execute that code.

Answer (score 1):

You can minify local names with `uglifyjs -m toplevel`.

As for folding, I believe it's usually not possible in javascript. In your particular case it'll work, but general code is usually too complex for static analyzer to do tricks like that.

Comment: Thanks... Looks like uglifyjs doesn't do folding. The closure compiler is clever enough to do it - it's just a shame that there doesn't seem to be an easy way to enable the functionality.

Comment: Just to add that while I know it can't be done all the time, in 99% of the cases I'm using it in, it's a massive help.